# Moving Files to a directory where filenames are unknown

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a scenario like this where there are files in a few directories. I don't know the file names. The file names are usually gibberish like `235443sdfsdf.sd` etc with little or no pattern in common.

I want to rename it into something like `abc.txt` and then copy it to a particular location.

Here is what i am having currently. I have two arrays

- `DirectoryToCopyFrom[]`

  This array contains the finite number of locations where the gibberish file exist. In each directory , there is just one gibberish file.
- `FileNameToReplace`

  This array contains the name to be replaced. Both the arrays have same number of elements with corresponding file location and the filename we want it to be.

This is the code that i came up with.

```
for ((i=0;i<${#DirectoryToCopyFrom[@]};i++))
     do

     for file in "${FileNameToReplace[$i]}/*"
         do
         if [ -f $file ];
             then

              mv $file ${FileNameToReplace[$i]}
         fi 
      done
 done
```

This appears to be buggy. can't understand what i am doing wrong here

Comment: If you use `"$var/*"`, you won't get glob expansion. Use `"$var"/*` instead.

Comment: "In each directory , there is just one gibberish file." `for ((i=0;i<${#DirectoryToCopyFrom[@]};i++)); do mv "${DirectoryToCopyFrom[i]}"/* "${FileNameToReplace[i]}"; done`

Comment: @anishsane sorry there was a typo . Updated the question .

Comment: @Santhiya, is your question already updated? Do your really iterate over "${FileNameToReplace[$i]}/*" ? Could you show an example of  content of these vars then?